# How to sort my dataframe after time date ? Why is it the sort worng?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, datetime

I want to sort my Dictionary by time.

If sort my Dictionary with the following code:

```
Dict["Nachts"].sort_values(by="Zeitpunkt",ascending=True)
```

I got this Dataframe:

[image: Dataframe of my Dict]

So the sort of my Dataframe is wrong, cause the date 01. Nov 2020 should be "taller" than 24.Oct.2020.

I formatted the data with:

```
{0:%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S}'.format(time)
```

Comment: if you want to sort based on string dtype, you'll need increasing resolution left to right, i.e. year-month-day-hour-mimute-second format, not d-m-y. Or you can sort based on a column that is of datetime dtype (not string).

Comment: in general: could you please clarify, do you have a `dict` or a `dataframe` to sort? can you provide sample data as text instead of image (would be helpful...)?

Comment: @MrFuppes thanks for the help and advice. I will note it next time.